# How to get ASP.NET website precompilation to exclude a certain folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, precompiling

The several different environments (e.g. live, demo etc) of my web app are differentiated by config settings in a folder called EnvironmentConfiguration. Whenever I update one of the sites, I delete the EnvironmentConfiguration folder from the precompiled site before copying the website files over (i.e. in order that the EnvironmentConfiguration folder in the deployment location is not replaced).

Just to save mistakes, is there a way I can get Visual Studio not to produce the EnvironmentConfiguration folder when it precompiles the site for me?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a couple of things.

1) Right click on the folder in the solution and select exclude from Project.

2) Look at each of the files in the folder and set the BuildAction property to 'None' rather than 'Content'

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1) The folder doesn't have the Exclude from Project option. 2) If the folder gets created, but not the contents, then an empty folder will be created which can still copy over a folder with the same name surely?

Comment: @David - The folder should not get overwritten even if its empty. I have a web application which is a main product, then sometimes there are amendments or extra pages for specific clients. I create a new web applicaiton and installer with the same folder names and install the second application after the first. Then the extra files get added to the folder rather then replacing the folder with only the contents of the second installer.